# Storing values from radio input button to SQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am doing online aptitude test for my company which will pick up 20 random questions from database and display it on webpage for answering.

But i have problem in storing answered values in SQl Database, Please any one can help me with this issue,

```
<?php


  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
  or die(mysql_error());
  $sel=mysql_select_db("aptitude");


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20 ");

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $q = $rows['QNo'];
    $qus = $rows['Question'];
    $a = $rows['Opt1'];
    $b = $rows['Opt2'];
    $c = $rows['Opt3'];
    $d = $rows['Opt4'];
    $ans = $rows['Ans'];


    echo "<b>Question:-<br></b>$qus <br>";
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$b'></input>$b &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$c'></input>$c &nbsp &nbsp "; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$d'></input>$d <br><br> ";


}

?>
```

but i am trying store values after user clicking on submit button:-

```
if (isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) 
{

$username=$_GET['username'];

$opt1=$_POST["answer1"];
$opt2=$_POST["answer2"];

mysql_query("insert into $username values('Q1','$answer1')")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("insert into $username values('Q2','$answer2')")
or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: what array you get in $_POST["answer"], after submitting form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While assigning the name value to input[type='radio'] tag your value is 'answer[1]' and while on submitting the form you are getting the value by $_POST['answer1']. Either change it while assigning the value to name attribute or change it while getting it through POST variable i.e:

Either

```
$_POST['answer[1]']
```

or

```
echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp";
```

Comment: $opt1=$_POST["answer[1]"];      $opt2=$_POST["answer[2]"];  ,....  i am using like this, is this correct way to get values,..

Comment: Ya there is a problem with square brackets used in name attribute value . PHP convert these character to underscore by default. Below is the link which would help you:

[link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)